# Clogged toilet in mobile home

Tags: plumbing

I cleaned my toilet and flushed all the blue cleaner down. The water barely went down. I purchased a 3' toilet snake which did nothing. I then used a much longer drain snake. Still nothing. I went to clean the toilet again due to all the splashing from snaking the drain. That's when I realized a large chunk of the toilet brush was gone which is obviously what clogged the toilet to begin with. I have no way of knowing how far in the obstruction is and can't afford $500 for a plumber. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably best to pull the toilet in order to use a heavy-duty motorized snake - you can rent them at Home Depot (or similar) or at a tool rental place. Not a trivial job, and many plumbers **will** charge $500 to do that. But it doesn't require true plumber expertise. But if you've never done anything like that before, at least a knowledgeable handyman would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The piece of the brush may still be stuck in the toilet. I have used toilet auggers on several occasions and gone past the blockage, pulled the toilet and the drain was fine, running the augger backwards through the toilet got the dog toy that was stuck , and it pushed the light bulb out into the bowl that my daughter flushed. A wax seal is only a few $ and toilets are not hard to pull 2 bolts and a water line, make sure to flush the water out of the toilet, I then like to use a shop vac to suck the water out of the trap because when the toilet is laid down to try and reverse augger the toilet water will leak out of the trap if not removed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where you are, but it's spring.

- Is this the only plumbing affected?

  - If it is, then the problem is between the toilet and the next device down hill. (toward the sewer)
  - If it isn't then you have a blockage further down.  At this point go under the trailer, and see if there are cleanout ports underneath.  Might save you pulling and restoring the toilet.
- Are all the devices affected?

  - Do you have a septic field, or has the weather been unseasonably cold?  If so, you may have a frozen line.